# Change text or show image within accordion header by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a view with a model that is a list of items.  Each of these items has an ID which I embed in the H2 header.  Details about the item are contained within the div below the header.  Within the header I have an image that is initially set to display:none.  I want to, with jquery script within the view, to either or both change the text in the header and/or make the image visible.

```
 <h2 id= 'header+@Model[i].ID' class="header" style="background-color:whitesmoke">@Model[i].Item.Name&nbsp 
                <img id="img+@Model[i].ID" src="~/Images/yes.gif" alt="" style="display:none" class="yescheck"/>
            </h2>
 <div>
     <table>
           // all the data
     </table>
     <button id="but+@Model[i].ID" onclick=CountComplete(); return false //...
 </div>
```

I have tried this:

```
 function CountComplete(but) {
    var id = but.id;
    id = id.substring(5);
    var div = "#div+" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: id },
        url: '@Url.Action("CountComplete")',
        success: function (data) {
            var test = data;
            $("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active', false);
            var head = '#header+' + id;
            var $image = $(head).find('.yescheck');
            $image.show();
            $('img+' + id).show();
            $(head).innerHTML = 'CLOSED';
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really simple: instead of using the plus sign '+' I used the minus sign '-' and JQ has no trouble at all finding the element.  I have no idea why the plus doesn't work.